# Python and C IPC

Tags: python, c, list, char, ipc

I'm currently developing a piece of software on a Raspberry Pi. Because I have to control motors very precisely i developed a C script, that does that for me. My current problem is, that I didn't found any solid method to transfer a list of signed floats from a Python3 Script to a C script. It is really important, that the method is fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a socket to send data from one script to the another.

Comment: @umgefahren Can’t you just do some research on sockets now?